# Ignore case in JArray C#

Tags: c#, json

I have response which I am converting to to JArray. But due to case sensitivity I am not able to get the values. I am using field `Unknown` but from response it is coming `UnKnown`, so am getting null result.

```
var jlist = JArray.Parse(response);
reasonId = jlist.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value<string>("AbsentReasonCD").Contains("Unknown"))
    .Value<string>("AbsentReasonId");
```

This is my data

```
 {
    "AbsentReasonId": 121,
    "AbsentReasonCD": "UnKnown"
  }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Equals` instead of `Contains`?

Comment: Thank for pointing. is there any plus using `Equals`

Comment: Of course, it's *faster* because it doesn't have to scan the entire string before it decides there's a mismatch. It will return `false` once it finds the first mismatch. `Contains` will match strings that contain `Unknown` anywhere in them, eg `this is not unknown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make the string lower case before checking:

```
var jlist = JArray.Parse(response);
reasonId = jlist.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Value<string>("AbsentReasonCD")
    .ToLower().Contains("unknown")).Value<string>("AbsentReasonId");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) instead which has an overload that takes a [comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
i.Value<string>("AbsentReasonCD")
 .IndexOf("Unknown", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find elements that actually *match* `Unknown` in a case insensitive manner you can use [String.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_) with the `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` parameter :

```
var jlist = JArray.Parse(response);
var reasonId = jlist.FirstOrDefault(i =>i.Value<string>("AbsentReasonCD")
                                         .Equals("Unknown",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    .Value<string>("AbsentReasonId");
```

or

```
var jlist = JArray.Parse(response);
var mode = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
var reasonId = jlist.FirstOrDefault(i =>i.Value<string>("AbsentReasonCD")
                                         .Equals("Unknown",mode))
                    .Value<string>("AbsentReasonId");
```

`Equals` will return `falses` as soon as the first mismatch is encountered. `Contains` or `IndexOf` on the other hand have to scan the entire string since `Unknown` may appear in the middle or at the end of the string.